# How do I watch for a successful payment (or order)?

Tags: payment, order-status

I need to run a very simple function when an order is set to complete and/or if the payment was successful.

If it's relevant we're using Global Transport for payment.  I mention it mostly because where I expect to see an order status go from "pending" to "complete" (as per documentation) it seems to stay as "pending"... this is possibly a red herring.

I'm almost losing track of the things I've tried:

- sales_order_invoice_save_after
- sales_order_payment_pay
- sales_order_place_after
- sales_order_payment_place_end

To be clear: I only need to run this function when payment is received for an order. These seem to run, but when I try to capture the order/payment object it's always "pending".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this observer:

```
checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
```

The observer return order_ids :

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer
{
    public function customFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getData('order_ids');
         //here you can add your custom code

    }        

}
```

Comment: this is great. I was hung up on trying to look too closely and track payment itself, but of course this works.